# Does `std::packaged_task` need a CopyConstructible constructor argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, future, packaged-task

I have this minimal not-working example of code

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    auto intTask = std::packaged_task<int()>( []()->int{ return 5; } );
    std::packaged_task<void()> voidTask{ std::move(intTask) };
}
```

Why doesn't it compile (on gcc 4.8.1)? I suspect, the reason is, that `std::packaged_task` stores the lambda internally inside an `std::function` which needs a `CopyConstructible` argument. However, `std::packaged_task` is move-only. Is this a bug? What does the standard say about it? In my opinion `std::packaged_task` should not need a `CopyConstructible` argument, but a `MoveConstructible` argument should be enough.

By the way, when I replace `std::packaged_task<int()>` by `std::packaged_task<void()>` everything compiles fine.

GCC 4.8.1 is giving me this error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/future:38:0,
                 from ../cpp11test/main.cpp:160:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In static member function 'static void        std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::packaged_task<int()>, std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1652:8:   instantiated from 'static bool std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::_Manager_operation) [with _Functor = std::packaged_task<int()>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:2149:6:   instantiated from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::packaged_task<int()>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void()>::_Useless]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:410:4:   instantiated from 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<_Tp, _Alloc, _Lp>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(_Alloc, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}, _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()> >, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:518:8:   instantiated from 'std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()> >, _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:987:35:   instantiated from 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()> >, _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}, _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:317:64:   instantiated from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()> >, _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}, _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:535:39:   instantiated from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()> >, _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/shared_ptr.h:551:42:   instantiated from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::__future_base::_Task_state<void()>, _Args = {std::packaged_task<int()>}]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1223:66:   instantiated from 'std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::packaged_task(_Fn&&) [with _Fn = std::packaged_task<int()>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {}]'
../cpp11test/main.cpp:165:61:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1616:4: error: use of deleted function 'std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::packaged_task(std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = int, _ArgTypes = {}, std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)> = std::packaged_task<int()>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1244:7: error: declared here
```

**UPDATE:** I have written the following test program. It seems to support the assumption that the reason is missing `CopyConstructability`. Again, what are the requirements on the type of the object from which an `std::packaged_task` may be constructed?

```
#include <future>

struct Functor {
    Functor() {}
    Functor( const Functor & ) {} // without this line it doesn't compile
    Functor( Functor && ) {}
    int operator()(){ return 5; }
};

int main() {
    auto intTask = std::packaged_task<int()>( Functor{} );
}
```

Comment: I revised my answer. You're falling over the `explicit` constructor.

Comment: Why are you trying to move a std::packaged_task<int()> into a std::packaged_task<void()>?

Comment: Actually I want to push `std::packaged_task<T()>` for any type `T` on a queue of `std::packaged_task<void()>`. I need a common type for the queue elements. The goal is to implement a thread pool which internally holds a concurrent queue of tasks. `std::function` will not be enough because I want to return `std::futures` for the results of the calculations.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question, and *should be* a completely different question.

Comment: I wanted to limit the scope of my question so I don't have to explain the entire problem. This question is where I got stuck. That's why I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard (as of N3690) doesn't state anything explicitly about the requirements of the type `F` in

```
template <class R, class... ArgTypes>
template <class F>
packaged_task<R(ArgTypes...)>::packaged_task(F&& f);
```

(see 30.6.9.1) However, it states that

> Invoking a copy of `f` shall behave the same as invoking `f`.

and that this call can throw

> any exceptions thrown by the copy or move constructor of `f`, or `std::bad_alloc` if memory
>   for the internal data structures could not be allocated.

This implicitly implies that the type `F` must be at least `MoveConstructible`, or `CopyConstructible`, if an lvalue reference is handed to the function.

Hence, it's not a bug, it's just not specified that precisely. To solve the problem of putting a `std::packaged_task<int()>` into a `std::packaged_task<void()>` just wrap the first into a `shared_ptr` like this:

```
#include <future>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto intTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<int()>>( 
        []()->int{ return 5; } );
    std::packaged_task<void()> voidTask{ [=]{ (*intTask)(); } };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `packaged_task` only has a moving constructor (30.6.9/2):

> `template <class F> explicit packaged_task(F&& f);`

However, your problem is the `explicit` constructor. So write it like this:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> pt([]() -> int { return 1; });
```

---

**Complete example:**

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> intTask([]() -> int { return 5; } );
    auto f = intTask.get_future();
    std::thread(std::move(intTask)).detach();
    return f.get();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The code fails to compile due to the second line in the `main()` function. I want to move a `std::packaged_task<int()>` into a `std::packaged_task<void()>`. I explained the reason for it in the comments to my question.

Answer (score 0):

No. You just can't move a `packaged_task<int ()>` into a `packaged_task<void ()>`. These types a unrelated and cannot be move-assigned or move-constructed from each other. If you for some reason really want to do that you can "swallow" the result of the `int ()` like [this](http://ideone.com/ScfGDM)

Comment: Unfortunately the solution in your link doesn't work for me, since the `intTask` will go out of scope before the `voidTask` is executed in my problem. The `[&]` capture is not good. But a `[=]` will also not do, because the `std::packaged_task` is not `Copyable`. Maybe a `std::shared_ptr` solution could work.

Comment: You simply cannot do that, the types are not compatible. You will need to provide a level of indirection which wraps both types into an instance of a common type. The return type of this new "task" type would need to be interrogated for the real run-time type.